How should I diagrammatically represent lego bricks in questions?
How should I represent:

2D plan view of bricks
Diagrams of brick interaction
3D views of models

Using markdown?

BrickML would be the way to go :)

Until we get BrickML enabled (is this going to happen?) we may just need to use images where it is a complex brick, or ASCII art for the simple ones

Short answer: However you like

Use which ever creative medium suites you and the audience:

You can usualy get your idea across with a rough sketch.
2D is best for two dimensional models such as brick walls, brick
profiles and building façades.
Photograph individual bricks or find an existing image on sites like Bricklink.
This question lists software for designing models in 3D using CAD (Computer Aided Design).

